# Not able to deploy LWC OSS app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, lightning-web-components, lwc-oss, node-salesforce

Getting the following error when I am trying to deploy an LWC OSS app to Heroku, I tried to deploy my app which had customizations got the same error, but now this is an LWC OSS fresh installation which I am trying to deploy. Still facing the issue.

Here is the Repo: https://github.com/somyatiwari59/SterlingCombine/tree/master

> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
> at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
> at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
> at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (/tmp/build_5ccc2cd6/node_modules/lwc-services/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:145:18)
> at BulkUpdateDecorator.update (/tmp/build_5ccc2cd6/node_modules/lwc-services/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:46:50)
> at RawSource.updateHash (/tmp/build_5ccc2cd6/node_modules/lwc-services/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/RawSource.js:64:8)
> at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/tmp/build_5ccc2cd6/node_modules/lwc-services/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:870:17)
> at handleParseResult (/tmp/build_5ccc2cd6/node_modules/lwc-services/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:936:10)
> at /tmp/build_5ccc2cd6/node_modules/lwc-services/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1028:4
> at processResult (/tmp/build_5ccc2cd6/node_modules/lwc-services/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:745:11)
> at /tmp/build_5ccc2cd6/node_modules/lwc-services/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:809:5
> node:internal/crypto/hash:67
> this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
> ^
> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
> at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
> at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
> at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (/tmp/build_5ccc2cd6/node_modules/lwc-services/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:145:18)
> at BulkUpdateDecorator.update (/tmp/build_5ccc2cd6/node_modules/lwc-services/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:46:50)
> at RawSource.updateHash (/tmp/build_5ccc2cd6/node_modules/lwc-services/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/RawSource.js:64:8)
> at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/tmp/build_5ccc2cd6/node_modules/lwc-services/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:870:17)
> at handleParseResult (/tmp/build_5ccc2cd6/node_modules/lwc-services/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:936:10)
> at /tmp/build_5ccc2cd6/node_modules/lwc-services/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1028:4
> at processResult (/tmp/build_5ccc2cd6/node_modules/lwc-services/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:745:11)
> at /tmp/build_5ccc2cd6/node_modules/lwc-services/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:809:5 {
> opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
> library: 'digital envelope routines',
> reason: 'unsupported',
> code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
> }
> Node.js v17.2.0
> -----> Build failed

```
   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added --openssl-legacy-provider in front of the build, build-development, start:client, and start:api commands, and my scripts in package.json looks as below:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "lwc-services --openssl-legacy-provider build -m production",
    "build:development": "lwc-services --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/**/*.js",
    "postinstall": "husky install",
    "precommit": "npm run prettier:verify && [ $? -eq 0 ] && npm run lint",
    "prettier": "prettier --write \"**/*.{css,html,js,json,md,ts,yaml,yml}\"",
    "prettier:verify": "prettier --list-different \"**/*.{css,html,js,json,md,ts,yaml,yml}\"",
    "start": "node --openssl-legacy-provider scripts/server.js",
    "start:api": "node --openssl-legacy-provider src/server/api.js",
    "start:client": "node --openssl-legacy-provider scripts/server.js",
    "test:unit": "lwc-services test:unit",
    "test:unit:coverage": "lwc-services test:unit --coverage",
    "test:unit:debug": "lwc-services test:unit --debug",
    "test:unit:watch": "lwc-services test:unit --watch",
    "watch": "run-p watch:client watch:server",
    "watch:client": "lwc-services watch",
    "watch:server": "nodemon"
}
```

Comment: The other option you can use is to change package.json `"engines": { "node": ">=10.13.0" ...` to `"engines": { "node": "14.x" ... }`, at least until they fix the SSL problem.

Comment: `--openssl-legacy-provider` is not best solution because  it's running with known insecure SSL https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man7/OSSL_PROVIDER-legacy.html.  as @sfdxfox said change engine to 14.x . heroku also recommends https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version